# Calling Delphi Code from script running in a TWebBrowser with object and function as parameters

Tags: delphi, ole, typelib

Based on [this article on DelphiDabbler](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=22&part=1), is it possible to include a pointer and/or function as calling parameter for callback purposes?

Assuming i have declarations as follows:

1. Type Library (.idl file)

   ```
   interface IMyExternal: IDispatch
   {
      [id(0x000000C9)]
      HRESULT _stdcall RequestData([in] variant lparam, [in] variant wparam, [in] bstr strparam, [out, retval] long Result);
   }
   ```
2. _tlb declaration

   ```pascal
   IMyExternal = interface(IDispatch)
     ['{E297C586-25F4-450A-A0F1-78D760506202}']
     function RequestData(const userdata, callback:variant; const strparam: WideString): longint; safecall;
   end;

   IMyExternalDisp = dispinterface
     ['{E297C586-25F4-450A-A0F1-78D760506202}']
     function RequestData(const userdata, callback:variant; const strparam: WideString): longint; dispid 201;
   end;
   ```
3. Usage

   ```pascal
   interface

   type
     IMycallback = function (userdata:variant; strdata:WideString):boolean;

     TMyExternal = class(TAutoIntfObject, IMyExternal, IDispatch)
       function RequestData(const userdata, callback:variant; const strparam: WideString): longint; safecall;
     end;

   implementation

   function TMyExternal.RequestData(const userdata, callback:variant; const strparam: WideString): longint;
   var
     cb  : IMycallback;
     n:integer;
   begin
     cb := callback;  //<<-- Main problem
     if assigned(cb) then
     begin
       n:=1;
       while cb(userdata,  format('Test line %d',[n])) do
       inc(n)
     end;
   end;
   ```
4. HTML/Javascrip :

   ```html
   <html>

   <head>
     <script>
     function TestCallback(userdata, strdata) {
       external.RequestData(userdata, function(userdata, strdata) {
         userdata.innerHTML = userdata.innerHTML + "<br>" + strdata;
         return false;
       }, strdata);
     }
     </script>
   </head>

   <body>
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="TestCallback(this,'hello world')">Test Callback</a>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

Is the problem related to assigning the callback to cb, or to using the wrong type for the input parameters?

Comment: Your `RequestData()` method requires 3 input parameters, but your JavaScript is passing in only 2 values to it. Your 3rd parameter is not optional. So JavaScript is likely to fail to call `RequestData()` at all. Beyond that, JavaScript has no concept of your `IMycallback` interface, so you can't assign a `Variant` provided by JavaScript to an `IMycallback` variable in your Delphi code, the assignment will fail. Just call `callback(...)` as if it were a normal function, even though it is really a `Variant`. Also, your Delphi code should be using `OleVariant` instead of `Variant`.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. Yes i made mistake with those two inputs. The last input should be an empty string. The problem is IMycallback. I really have no idea how to declare a function with two inputs (one is pointer and another is string) that could be use by both, delphi and javascript.

Comment: You can't pass around raw pointers. All objects in a scripting environment are implemented in terms of `IDispatch`, which `Variant`/`OleVariant` natively supports.  That is why I said you should be able to call `callback(...)` *as if* it were a function, eg: `callback(userdata, strdata)`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That should be the most acceptable explanation. But now i'm stuck on calling `callback(lparam, 'test');` with compiler error:` E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'OleVariant' found`.

Comment: Then you will likely have to assign the callback `OleVariant` to an `IDispatch` variable so you can then call its [`Invoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479.aspx) method directly (see  the `DispatchInvoke()` wrapper in the `ComObj` unit), using `DISPID_VALUE` in the `dispIdMember` parameter, `DISPATCH_METHOD` in the `wFlags` parameter, and an array of `OleVariant` values in the `pDispParams` parameter. See [Invoking JavaScript Callbacks Using COM Automation](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/invoking-javascript-callbacks-using-com/184416311).

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Ok, thank you very much. I'll try that one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123823/discussion-between-theodorusap-and-remy-lebeau).